# java animation android duration

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, duration

This animation isn't animating it just instantly disappears no matter what duration I set
here is the java code and xml

Java Code:

```
Animation shrink =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Page.this, R.anim.shrink);
    deleteMe.startAnimation(shrink);
```

XML File:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" 
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="10000">
    <scale
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0" >
    </scale>
    <alpha
        android:duration="10000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0">
    </alpha>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my app i write this code to move a block from left to right and its working well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<rotate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:startOffset="1500"/>

<translate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" 
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="3000"/>

<translate android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:startOffset="1500" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify **android:interpolator** attribute of set tag with the value you desired.
This interpolator just moves the object from the start point to the end point (or rotation) at a steady rate.

for ex::

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
```

Comment: Do i need to do this for each element or just for the root set element

Comment: I added this and updated the code and edited the post still doesn't work...*sigh*